# Numpy:memory efficient way to produce np.exp(1j*x), for real x

Tags: numpy, memory-management, numpy-ndarray

For a given real numpy array x,
`np.exp(1j*x)`'s peak memory consumption seems to be 4 times X (memory size of `x`). And this seems to be because: first it computes `result=1j*np.sin(x)`, with peak memory use of 4X, going back to 2X, then computes `result+=np.cos(x)` with peak memory use of 4X, coming back to 2X. However, `np.exp(1j*x)`'s size should be 2X. Is there any way to reduce the peak memory to 2X?

Comment: No, if first does `1j*x` for size 2X.  That is passed to `np.exp`.  Internally that may be doing the `sin` and `cos`, but I don't think we can identify what.  Depending on how you record the size, I can picture it peaking at 4X, the space for `1j*x` and for the `exp` result.  Some suggest `numexpr` as faster, and possibly less memory intensive.

Comment: if `x` is of type float64, then `1j*x` will be of type complex128 which takes 2x the memory space and `exp` need also to allocate the output since it does not perform the operation in-place, hence a 4X. Consider operating on chunks, or using Numba/Cython/Numexpr.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thank you. I will consider Numexpr. What do you mean by "the operation in-place"?

Comment: Some functions have an `out` parameter so to write data in a given array. If the input and output matches and the computation allows it (eg. basic ones operating on each items separately), then the computation is in-place. An example is `np.add`

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments, the 4x peak comes from `1j*x` taking 2x the storage of `x` and then the result of `exp()` also taking 2x.

Also as already mentioned Numba/Cython/Numexpr can do the operation without intermediate arrays and in a single loop.

The 4x peak can be avoided using only numpy, but it requires 2 loops over `x`:

```
result = np.empty_like(x, np.result_type(x, 1j))
np.sin(x, out=result.imag)
np.cos(x, out=result.real)
```

Comment: This seems to use 3X peak memory